# How do I properly reset buffer so next read is correct?

Tags: c, codewarrior

My project involves sending commands from PuTTY to a Dragon12-Plus2 development board(CodeWarrior 5.1) via an XBEE Wifi. I am using 4 commands to control the leds on the Dragon board {led_enable(), leds_on(integer in hex or decimal here), leds_off(), and led_disable()} from the LBE_DRAGON12_Plus project from LBEbooks.com. Here is my code:

```
// Final Project: Control leds via XBEE Wifi
#include <hidef.h>      /* common defines and macros */
#include <mc9s12dg256.h>     /* derivative information */
#include "queue.h"
#pragma LINK_INFO DERIVATIVE "mc9s12dg256b"

#include "main_asm.h" /* interface to the assembly module */

void main(void){
  int x,y,z,parser;
  int cmdLen = 0;                    
  char c,d,e;
  char cbuff[20];
  PLL_init();                             // set system clock frequency to 24 MHz 
  lcd_init();                             // enable lcd
  SCI1_init(9600);                        // initialize SCI1 at 9600 baud
  SCI0_init(9600);                        // initialize SCI0 at 9600 baud
  seg7_disable();                         // disable 7 segment display
  led_enable();                           // enable 8 leds
  while(1){
    if(SCI1SR1_RDRF == 1){
      c = inchar1();
      cbuff[cmdLen] = c;
      outchar0(cbuff[cmdLen]);
      if(c == ';'){
        if((cbuff[0] == 'l') && (cbuff[10] == ';')){
          leds_off();
          cmdLen = 0;
        } 
        else if((cbuff[0] == 'l') && (cbuff[12] == ';')){
          led_enable();
          cmdLen = 0;
        } 
        else if((cbuff[0] == 'l') && (cbuff[4] == 'd')){
          led_disable();
          cmdLen = 0;
        }
        else if((cbuff[0] == 'l') && (cbuff[13] == ';')){
          d = cbuff[10];
          e = cbuff[11];
          switch(d){                        // change first number to integer
            case('0'):
              x = 0x00;
              break;
            case('1'):
              x = 0x10;
              break;
            case('2'):
              x = 0x20;
              break;
            case('3'):
              x = 0x30;
              break;
            case('4'):
              x = 0x40;
              break;
            case('5'):
              x = 0x50;
              break;
            case('6'):
              x = 0x60;
              break;
            case('7'):
              x = 0x70;
              break;
            case('8'):
              x = 0x80;
              break;
            case('9'):
              x = 0x90;
              break;
            case('a'):
              x = 0xa0;
              break;
            case('b'):
              x = 0xb0;
              break;
            case('c'):
              x = 0xc0;
              break;
            case('d'):
              x = 0xd0;
              break;
            case('e'):
              x = 0xe0;
              break;
            case('f'):
              x = 0xf0;   
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
          switch(e){                        // change second number to integer
            case('0'):
              y = 0x00;
              break;
            case('1'):
              y = 0x01;
              break;
            case('2'):
              y = 0x02;
              break;
            case('3'):
              y = 0x03;
              break;
            case('4'):
              y = 0x04;
              break;
            case('5'):
              y = 0x05;
              break;
            case('6'):
              y = 0x06;
              break;
            case('7'):
              y = 0x07;
              break;
            case('8'):
              y = 0x08;
              break;
            case('9'):
              y = 0x09;
              break;
            case('a'):
              y = 0x0a;
              break;
            case('b'):
              y = 0x0b;
              break;
            case('c'):
              y = 0x0c;
              break;
            case('d'):
              y = 0x0d;
              break;
            case('e'):
              y = 0x0e;
              break;
            case('f'):
              y = 0x0f;
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
          z = (x + y);                      // add integers together
          leds_on(z);                       // display hex number on leds
          cmdLen = 0;                       // reset parser

        }
        for(parser = 0; parser < 20; parser++){
          cbuff[parser] = '\0';
        }
      }
      cmdLen++;
    }  
  }
}
```

The first command i send works as expected (for instance if i type leds_on(0xaa); in PuTTY the 4 corresponding leds light up), but any command I send after does nothing. I am not sure how to properly reset cbuff so that it operates the same way each time, not just the first time.

EDITED TO SHOW SUGGESTED CHANGES!

Comment: You are correct that part of the problem is that you do not clear the contents of `cbuff` between commands, but you shouldn't need to do.  The bigger problem is that you are testing after each keystroke whether the buffer contains a recognized command, and resetting the parser if it does.

Comment: this line: 'void main(void){' is not valid, and should have raised a compiler warning.  The correct line would be: 'int main(){'

Comment: a table of the desired values, and using the (currently switch(parm)) parm as an index into the table would make the code orders of magnitude smaller and significantly faster.

Comment: there are numerous problems with the code, here is one:  this line: 'if((cptr[0] == 'l') && (cptr[10] == ';')){' is accessing cptr[10] (which initially contains trash) when only 1 (or so) characters have been read.  This is one form of undefined behaviour.

Comment: variables 'd' and 'e' are being set/evaluated before the source data bytes have been read in.  suggest a loop to get bytes, and when full command received, THEN (and not before then) process the data.  the 'cptr' variable (which really is NOT needed) points to 'cbuff' and all your references could simply be 'cbuff[x]' and eliminate the 'cptr' variable.

Comment: I was trying something else with the pointer before I posted the issue on stack. Also so far all the problems you have listed have been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clear all of the elements in the array, then `memset` would be a wise choice:

```
memset(cbuff, 0, 20);
```

That being said, I would strongly agree with @John Bollinger that separating the input and the interpretation functionality would be wise.

However, depending on the application `memset` might be overkill. A simple cleared array may also be achieved by simply setting the elements of the array to null character (`'\0'`). Simply call `cbuff[0] = '\0'` for each element in the array.

Comment: Using this gives me an error "result of function call is ignored".

Comment: Still returns result of call is ignored.

Comment: Hmmm. I have posted an alternative solution.

Comment: that is because your compiler is not recognizing the fact that cptr is accessing cbuff.  Just another good reason to eliminate cptr and always use cbuff[x].  BTW: a better statement would be: memset( cbuff, 0x00, sizeof(cbuff),  because then you could change the size of cbuff without changing any other code

Comment: Writing it as "memset(cbuff, 0x00, sizeof(cbuff))" gives "implicit parameter-declaration for memset" and "result of function call is ignored".

Comment: Try just iterating through the buffer and replacing each element with `'\0'`. Like: `int cbuffsize = sizeof(cbuff);
for (int i = 0; i < cbuffsize; i++)
{
 cbuff[i] = ‘\0’;
}`

Comment: That is how it is set up now and it doesn't throw an error but the next run through the loop still doesn't execute a command.

Answer (score 1):

What an odd parser.  I'd suggest you separate your input stage from your command interpretation stage.  That is, read and count characters until you receive a semicolon (`;`) command terminator, and only then try to interpret the command.

Reset the `parser` variable (which would more accurately be named something like `command_length`) only after each attempt to interpret the command, whether successful or not, or if the buffer is about to overflow.

Comment: I took this into consideration and made the suggested changes. Now the first command "leds_on(0x55);" turns on the correct leds, but then i type "leds_off();" and the bit 8 and bit 6 leds come on?? This is really screwy...

Comment: The most likely explanations for the new behavior are: (1) your program does something different from calling `leds_off()` when it receives the command "leds_off()"; (2) the `leds_off()` function does not work correctly; (3) after processing the "leds_off()" command by calling `leds_off()`, your program calls some other function (i.e. `leds_on()`) that turns some LEDs on again.